# Make [odor] a synonym of [smell]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[odor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) [smell](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell)

There's no compelling reason to keep these separate. [odor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) doesn't even have an excerpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing an [odor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) tag. If there was before, the questions with that tag have been retagged and the system will delete an empty tag automatically. The [odors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odors) tag is already configured as a synonym of [smell](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell) and has been for many years now. The only additional step we can take is to merge the tags so that very old questions with the [odors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odors) tag get retagged.

Comment: Yeah, looks like someone burninated it by retag (it definitely existed before). Guess we can synonym if someone recreates it.